# What is the word for someone who is willing to do anything for a fee

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns

My character Laila is a sort of allrounder, jack of all trades and will do anything, from being your lawyer or temporary girlfriend to going undercover in the government, assassinating someone or even dropping a bomb in New York and she does not care even if the person hiring her is the mafia boss or the American government or even just a roadside beggar as long as she gets her pay. What should I call her?

Example sentence:

> Laila makes her living as a ______.

Comment: You want something that describes her personality or her skill set or her occupation?

Comment: I've edited your question to include a sentence showing how your word would be used, as your question is at risk of closure without it - see the tag info for [tag:single-word-requests]. If my sentence doesn't capture the sense you're after – for instance, you're focussing on personality or skill set (as @KillingTime has already asked you to clarify) – please [edit] it. For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try ***mercenary***

Defined by [Oxford DictionarIes](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mercenary) as:

> Primarily concerned with making money at the expense of ethics.

Your Laila is a *mercenary* of the highest order.